# Failed to load the js file component in console[Magento 2]

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, magento2

I am trying to show current time with running seconds on a page under adminhtml. I wrote the code for js in Namespace_Module/view/adminhtml/web/js/timejs.js And the code is

```
define(
['jquery', 'uiComponent', 'ko']
,function ($, Component, ko) {
    'use strict';
        return Component.extend({
      defaults: {
        template: 'Pixelnet_Blog/time'
      },

      initialize: function () {
            this._super();
            this.currentTime();
        },


      currentTime: ko.computed(function () {
        setInterval(function(){
          var currentTime = new Date().toLocaleTimeString();
          // console.log(currentTime);
        }, 1000);
        return currentTime;
      })
    });
}
);
```

To render the js function I created a PHTML in the place of Namespace_Module/view/adminhtml/templates/js_time.phtml and the code is

```
<div id="time_show" data-bind="scope:'time_show'">
<!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{
    "*": {
        "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
            "components": {
                "time_show": {
                    "component": "Pixelnet_Blog/js/timejs"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
</div>
```

I called the template in the phtml and put the template in the position of Namespace_Module/view/adminhtml/web/template/time.html. And HTML code is

```
<div>
    <h4>Current Time is:</h4><span id="time_show" data-bind="text: currentTime()"></span>
</div>
```

lastly, I put a require js file in the location of Namespace_Module/view/adminhtml/requirejs-config.js and the code snippet is

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            timejs: 'Pixelnet_Blog/js/timejs'
        }
    }
};
```

But when I render the page it does not show the time with running seconds. In console, it shows an error named Failed to load the "Pixelnet_Blog/js/timejs" component. I cannot figure out the problem.